# How to write proper string to work with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've got a problem with my node.js application.
I'm trying to parse string using JSON.parse like this:

```
try{
    skills = JSON.parse(user.skills);
    }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

In user.skills I've got such a string:

```
"[ { name: Dreamweaver, level: 60 }, { name: Phototshop, level: 80 }]"
```

and it throws me: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token n].
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't have valid JSON, which is why it fails. Valid JSON has doublequotes around both keys and values that are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data is incorrect. There should be quotes `""` around strings.

should be like this

```
var str = "[ { \"name\": \"Dreamweaver\", \"level\": 60 }, { \"name\": \"Phototshop\", \"level\": 80 }]"
```

If you want to see how should be a proper JSON String Try this

```
var data = {name:"mark"}
JSON.stringify(data) //returns "{"name":"mark"}" Here you have to care about escaping quotes.
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried "" before but it didn't work and \"\" works thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

JSON data needs identifiers and values to be strings, try this:

```
'[ { "name": "Dreamweaver", "level": "60" }, { "name": "Phototshop", "level": "80" }]';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to varify json. After that we can stringify and parse json respectively.